# How to disable logged warnings in Pybel?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, openbabel, pybel

I am using Pybel - a Python wrapper around the OpenBabel API, and I am trying to disable warnings such as these:

```
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in ParseComplex
  Illegal aromatic element b-
```

My warnings were raised consistently when fingerprinting molecule **SMILES** fetched from **ChEMBL**

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a handle to the openbabel logger (the class `OBMessageHandler`) off of the `openbabel` module. The trick is to first **access the openbabel module off of the pybel module**, grab the `OBMessageHandler` class, and instantiate the logger ([docs](http://openbabel.org/dev-api/classOpenBabel_1_1OBMessageHandler.shtml)):

```
import pybel

ob_log_handler = pybel.ob.OBMessageHandler()
```

Using the handle, you can set the `log_level` to **0** to disable *all but critical messages* ([docs](http://openbabel.org/dev-api/classOpenBabel_1_1OBMessageHandler.shtml#ae467fbd6fca625ae5ee0ea066810280f)):

```
ob_log_handler.SetOutputLevel(0)
```

You can use the following enumerations ([docs here](http://openbabel.org/dev-api/namespaceOpenBabel.shtml#acf195409ac7024002db5c178f20862d9)) to choose your level of logging. The default is **1**, which logs all **warnings**:

- **0**: Critical
- **1**: Warning (*default*)
- **2**: Info
- **3**: Audit (*when molecules are destroyed/perceived*)
- **4**: Debug

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of all error messages:

```py
pybel.ob.obErrorLog.StopLogging()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Aelfinn's answer didn't work for me, but accessing  SetOutputLevel this way did:

`pybel.ob.obErrorLog.SetOutputLevel(0)`